# Pandas fillna for chronologically ordered dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe of some time series data which contains some missing dates. I want to fill these based on the dates in the adjacent rows.

For example, the entries in the dataframe are chronologically ordered thus I know that the two missing dates in the below dataframe must also be 15/3/22 because the above and below entires are both 15/3/22.

| Date | Time | etc. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 15/3/22 | 1:34:40 AM | ... |
| NaN | 1:36:18 AM | ... |
| NaN | 1:36:20 AM | ... |
| 15/3/22 | 3:08:23 AM | ... |

Alternatively, when the entries are days apart, you won't be able to tell which date the missing values should be (3/3, 4/3, or 5/3) and thus they should be left as NaN.

| Date | Time | etc. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 03/3/22 | 8:50:15 AM | ... |
| NaN | 10:40:00 AM | ... |
| NaN | 12:10:40 AM | ... |
| 05/3/22 | 3:08:23 AM | ... |

How can I do this in Pandas? Thanks

Sample code to create the example dataframes:

```
data1 = [['15/3/22', '1:34:40'], ['', '1:36:18'], ['', '1:36:20'],['15/3/22', '3:08:23']]
data2 = [['03/3/22', '8:50:15'], ['', '10:40:00'], ['', '12:10:40'], ['05/3/22', '3:08:23']]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['Date', 'Time'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['Date', 'Time'])

df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime( df1['Date'], format='%d/%m/%y', errors="coerce" )
df1['Time'] = pd.to_datetime( df1['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S', errors="coerce" )
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime( df2['Date'], format='%d/%m/%y', errors="coerce" )
df2['Time'] = pd.to_datetime( df2['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S', errors="coerce" )
```

Comment: Interesting question - would you be able to include a code snippet that generates this example data? It would help us answering if we can easily test our solution directly on the data you've included. (I imagine you've got this data from an external source, so it might feel a bit strange writing code to just create it directly in your script, but it's useful to have it like that as part of a "minimal reproducible example" kind of thing.)

Comment: @Tim I have edited the question to include some sample code to produce the example dataframes. Hopefully it's what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks! I posted my answer just after you edited it so hadn't seen it before I did so, but I've just tried it out now and it looks like my technique works! 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of good examples of various strategies for filling missing data in the documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/missing_data.html#filling-missing-values-fillna

I don't think a particular method exists that follows the filling strategy you've described (though it is a very reasonable one), but I think we can use a trick to achieve it quite easily: by doing a forward-fill and a backward-fill and then only keeping the changes when these two give the same result, which must be when it's the same date before and after the run of `NaN`s.

```
date_ff = df["Date"].fillna(method="ffill")
date_bf = df["Date"].fillna(method="bfill")

df.loc[date_ff == date_bf, "Date"] = date_ff
```

In case you're unfamiliar with the `.loc` syntax, that last line is filtering to just the rows where `date_ff` and `date_bf` are equal and setting the Date column to the corresponding value from `date_ff` (we could have used `date_bf` - the point is that they give exactly the same result).

Note that since the non-`NaN` values aren't touched by `fillna()` they will be equal in `date_ff` and `date_bf` so are effectively left unchanged.